# Simple way to send short messages between Android phone

Tags: android

This is more of a design question. I'm very new to Android.

Is there a simple and relatively inexpensive way to send short messages, a couple of bytes each, between Android phones? The idea would be similar to Whatsapp but not for chatting. It's for phone-to-phone coordination.

I'm thinking of renting a VPS hosting service and install a message broker (Qpid or RabbitMQ) on it! But that doesn't sound scalable or Android idiomatic and I haven't even looked at how to implement push notification with this message broker.

Another way is to have a server app on VPS and connect that server with Google Cloud Messaging. The server app is still a bottleneck and I have to pay for both VPS and Google Cloud Messaging.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSD to acheive this.

Refer to the [Link](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html)

The Sample App is a simple Chat app .This will give you an idea.

Comment: Thanks Nargis. But NSD works only on local network where there isn't any firewall or NAT involved.